# Linq InsertAllOnSubmit if not exist

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

To insert records if not exist I'm currently doing:

```
using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
{
    for(int i=0 i<Items.Length;i++)
    {
        if(!db.Items.Any(item=> item.name == Items[i].name)
            db.Items.InsertOnSubmit(Items[i]);
    }
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

I know that I can also check these Items one by one and insert non-existing ones into another list and then at the end insert all of them using `InsertAllOnSubmit()` but this does not solve my problem either as I'm going to check thousand of Items and I don't want to execute thouthand queries for checking these Items. Is there any way to use InsertAllOnSibmit in a way that insert only non-exsiting Items?

**Edit:** I have no obligation to use Linq and if somebody knows a better way to do this by stored procedures or any other way I really I appreciate if you share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One query to figure out what needs to be inserted, then after some in-memory manipulation you can `InsertAllOnSubmit`:

```
using(MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
{
    var itemNames = Items.Select(i=>i.name).ToList();
    var itemNamesInDb = db.Items.Where(i=>itemNames.Contains(i.Name)).Select(i=>i.Name).ToList();
    var itemNamesNotInDb = new HashSet<string>(itemNames.Except(itemNamesInDb));
    var itemsNotInDb = Items.Where(i=>itemNamesNotInDb.Contains(i.name)).ToList();

    db.Items.InsertAllOnSubmit(itemsNotInDb);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: `i=>itemNames.Contains(i)` Strange predicate.

Comment: It can be worse, if db has 5 million items to select them all into memory to execute where method  to get itemNamesInDb.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your objection correctly, @vitalygolub, the Where is not executed in local memory; it will be translated by EF into a WHERE...IN clause in the generated sql, to be executed on the database server.

Comment: if there are lots of records in my table, would effect your solution performance wise?

Comment: Having many records in db.Items should not penalize the query too much, especially if there is an index on Name.  But you should be aware that there *is* a limit on the number of items in the Items collection that this can handle (EF limitation).  If you run up against that limitation, you'd want to split up these queries (make a separate function that, given the DbContext and a list of Items, gets itemsNotInDb; split up the original list of Items, call that function on each sub-list, and concat up the results prior to InsertAllOnSubmit).

Comment: A lot of those `ToList()` calls are unnecessary, you only really need it for `itemNames`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try somthing like:
note, that concurrency could be an issue this way, the only way I see this working properlly is with store procedures and blocking strategies in place, but if want to do it with L2SQL...

```
//1st db hit, to get the existing records, existing count never superior to toInsert count, 
//so it should not comsume a lot of memory
var existing = db.Items.Where(p => toInsert.Contains(p.Name)).ToList();

foreach (var input in toInsert)
{
    //fast in memory lookup
    if (existing.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name== input) == null)
    {
       //insert the element
    }
}

//2nd db hit - submit to DB
```

Comment: would you please tell me how to do it with stored procedure?

Comment: there is no obligation to use linq. If you have a better suggestion using stored procedure. I'd really appreciate.

Comment: I can but this is out  of the scope of the question as you tag it linq, retag with SQL or Transact-SQL and you get the gurus here with Store Procedures. =)

Comment: I edited my question and its not completely in scope ;)

Comment: As is, you're performing a query for every item to be inserted. `existing` is an `IQueryable<Item>`. You would have to convert that to a list at least.

Comment: @JeffMercado thanks for the observation!, added the correction.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be *that* complicated.  The names appear to be the primary keys.  Just figure out which of the names in the database are in your set of items to insert.  Then insert them excluding the ones that existed.

```
var excludedNames = new HashSet<string>(
    from i in db.Items
    where Items.Select(item => item.Name).Contains(i.Name)
    select i.Name
);
db.Items.InsertAllOnSubmit(
    from i in Items
    where !excludedNames.Contains(i.Name)
    select i
);
db.SubmitChanges();
```